# Wrong USB Location address of the FT4222 on my Windows7

Tags: c, windows-7, usb, ftdi

I have a windows 7 laptop (Sony pcg 81113M) with 3 USB ports, When I connect 2 * Ft 4222HQ and I run the "Getting start code for the Ft4222" (C++ Qtcreator) I get a wrong USB location which is 0x00. The same when I connect only one in that specific 2 ports.

[image]

I am verifying the USB-location of connected FTDI using the software USBview.

[image]

I am using "connect by location" in my program and if I connect two at the same time It will conseder it as one device (cause the Location Id is the same)

The FTDI driver is the latest version and i see all the interfaces in my device manager

[image]

Note: the third USB port works normally and I get a correct Location Id:

[image]

[image]

The os is a win7 64bit, the FTDI code runs on the 32bit (I also get the same result with 64bit)

Do anyone has an Idea about that? is there some other test that I can do it to figure it out the problem?

Here is Getting started FTDI code:

[source] https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/LibFT4222-v1.4.4.zip

```
void ListFtUsbDevices()
{
    FT_STATUS ftStatus = 0;

    DWORD numOfDevices = 0;
    ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numOfDevices);

    for(DWORD iDev=0; iDev<numOfDevices; ++iDev)
    {
        FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE devInfo;
        memset(&devInfo, 0, sizeof(devInfo));

        ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail(iDev, &devInfo.Flags, &devInfo.Type, &devInfo.ID, &devInfo.LocId,
                                        devInfo.SerialNumber,
                                        devInfo.Description,
                                        &devInfo.ftHandle);

        if (FT_OK == ftStatus)
        {
            printf("Dev %d:\n", iDev);
            printf("  Flags= 0x%x, (%s)\n", devInfo.Flags, DeviceFlagToString(devInfo.Flags).c_str());
            printf("  Type= 0x%x\n",        devInfo.Type);
            printf("  ID= 0x%x\n",          devInfo.ID);
            printf("  LocId= 0x%x\n",       devInfo.LocId);
            printf("  SerialNumber= %s\n",  devInfo.SerialNumber);
            printf("  Description= %s\n",   devInfo.Description);
            printf("  ftHandle= 0x%x\n",    devInfo.ftHandle);

            const std::string desc = devInfo.Description;
            if(desc == "FT4222" || desc == "FT4222 A")
            {
                g_FT4222DevList.push_back(devInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ListFtUsbDevices();   

    if(g_FT4222DevList.empty()) {
        printf("No FT4222 device is found!\n");
        return 0;
    }


    ftStatus = FT_OpenEx((PVOID)g_FT4222DevList[0].LocId, FT_OPEN_BY_LOCATION, &ftHandle);
    if (FT_OK != ftStatus)
    {
        printf("Open a FT4222 device failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Init FT4222 as SPI master\n");
    ftStatus = FT4222_SPIMaster_Init(ftHandle, SPI_IO_SINGLE, CLK_DIV_4, CLK_IDLE_LOW, CLK_LEADING, 0x01);
    if (FT_OK != ftStatus)
    {
        printf("Init FT4222 as SPI master device failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("TODO ...\n");
    printf("\n");


    printf("UnInitialize FT4222\n");
    FT4222_UnInitialize(ftHandle);

    printf("Close FT device\n");
    FT_Close(ftHandle);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/TN_152_USB_3.0_Compatibility_Issues_Explained.pdf Section *2.1.2 Location ID Returned As 0*

> LocationIDs are not strictly part of the USB spec in the format
> provided by FTDI. The feature was added as an additional option to
> back up identifying and opening ports by index, serial number or
> product description strings.
>
> When connected to a USB 2.0 port the location is provided on the basis
> of the USB port that the device is connected to. These values are
> derived from specific registry keys. As the registry tree for 3rd
> party USB 3.0 host drivers is different to the Microsoft generic
> driver the Location ID cannot be calculated.
>
> There is no workaround to this current issue and as such devices
> should be listed and opened by index, serial number or product
> description strings.

So this is known behaviour. Btw Win 7 EOL date was january 2020. Changing the OS is strongly adviced.